# Outlook 2010 Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers for Context Menu

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

With a VSTO Outlook 2010 addin what is the Context Menu ID for the following text cases;

1. Where the email has bullet points or is numbered
2. Where the text is a URL link that Outlook has recognised as a link
3. Where the user copies from Excel and it is kind of a table.

I have added the IDs below from Word as I think the ID I need are from Words list.

```
ContextMenuDropCap  contextMenu
ContextMenuEndnote  contextMenu
ContextMenuField    contextMenu
ContextMenuFieldDisplay contextMenu
ContextMenuFieldDisplayListNumbers  contextMenu
ContextMenuFieldForm    contextMenu
ContextMenuFootnote contextMenu
ContextMenuFrame    contextMenu
ContextMenuHeading  contextMenu
ContextMenuHeadingLinked    contextMenu
ContextMenuScriptAnchor contextMenu
ContextMenuList contextMenu
ContextMenuInlinePicture    contextMenu
ContextMenuTable    contextMenu
ContextMenuTableCell    contextMenu
ContextMenuHeadingTable contextMenu
ContextMenuListTable    contextMenu
ContextMenuPictureTable contextMenu
ContextMenuTextTable    contextMenu
ContextMenuTableWhole   contextMenu
ContextMenuTableWholeLinked contextMenu
ContextMenuText contextMenu
ContextMenuOfficePreviewHandlerWord contextMenu
ContextMenuTextLinked   contextMenu
ContextMenuRichTextFont contextMenu
ContextMenuRichTextFontParagraph    contextMenu
ContextMenuSpell    contextMenu
ContextMenuGrammar  contextMenu
ContextMenuGrammarReading   contextMenu
ContextMenuRevision contextMenu
ContextMenuFramesetBorder   contextMenu
ContextMenuHyperlink    contextMenu
ContextMenuFieldAutoSignatureList   contextMenu
ContextMenuFieldAutoTextList    contextMenu
ContextMenuNavigationPane   contextMenu
ContextMenuDrawnObject  contextMenu
ContextMenuCurve    contextMenu
ContextMenuCurveNode    contextMenu
ContextMenuCurveSegment contextMenu
ContextMenuFloatingPicture  contextMenu
ContextMenuCanvasClassic    contextMenu
ContextMenuOleObject    contextMenu
ContextMenuActiveXControl   contextMenu
ContextMenuTextEffect   contextMenu
ContextMenuComment  contextMenu
ContextMenuOrganizationChart    contextMenu
ContextMenuDiagram  contextMenu
ContextMenuConnectorClassic contextMenu
ContextMenuAddressBlock contextMenu
ContextMenuGreetingLine contextMenu
ContextMenuInlineActiveXControl contextMenu
ContextMenuDocumentStructureNode    contextMenu
ContextMenuXmlError contextMenu
ContextMenuCoAuthoringState contextMenu
ContextMenuInkComment   contextMenu
ContextMenuInlineBusinessCard   contextMenu
ContextMenuEquation contextMenu
ContextMenuHeaderArea   contextMenu
ContextMenuFooterArea   contextMenu
ContextMenuReadOnlyMailText contextMenu
ContextMenuReadOnlyMailTable    contextMenu
ContextMenuReadOnlyMailTableCell    contextMenu
ContextMenuReadOnlyMailListTable    contextMenu
ContextMenuReadOnlyMailPictureTable contextMenu
ContextMenuReadOnlyMailTextTable    contextMenu
ContextMenuReadOnlyMailTableWhole   contextMenu
ContextMenuReadOnlyMailList contextMenu
ContextMenuReadOnlyMailHyperlink    contextMenu
ContextMenuLockedReadingMode    contextMenu
ContextMenuPageNumberingOptions contextMenu
ContextMenuConflicts    contextMenu
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone coming here to get an answer there are two things to understand which helps alot.

(1) Even though you are doing this in Outlook, when you are writing and reading text in many Outlook inspectors (the windows) it is actually related to Word and so the context menus of Word apply.

(2) On a higher level there are 2 kinds of context menus in Outlook.  Compose menu and then readOnly ones which is for example when you are reading an email.

To specifically answer my question above.

Reading Only parts of Outlook

1. bullet points - ContextMenuReadOnlyMailList
2. url - ContextMenuReadOnlyMailHyperlink
3. table - ContextMenuReadOnlyMailTable

Composing an email for example

1. bullet points - ContextMenuList
2. url - ContextMenuHyperlink
3. table - ContextMenuTable

But the best thing I have found is [this blog in Japanese.](http://suyamasoft.blue.coocan.jp/WordVBA/Ribbon/ContextMenuID/index.html) I cannot read Japanese either but there is an example [here to download.](http://suyamasoft.blue.coocan.jp/WordVBA/Ribbon/ContextMenuID/ContextMenuID.lzh) Simply type the text or item you want in the Word document and right click on it and the context menu type is shown in the context menu.  Ive been looking for this for a long time.

Somebody in the stackoverflow admin really needs to look at giving a negative vote. It helps nobody without a comment to know why the person is voting it down.

Comment: That Japanese blog was the key.